# CSS Images, and Others Blocking First Paint

Tags: css, performance, google-chrome, pagespeed

I am noticing a really strange waterfall in chrome that suggests that CSS images, and other images are preventing the first paint. I've hidden rendering events but they are intermingled throughout the waterfall (you can load it yourself at www.lonestarpercussion.com)

I'm not sure why chrome is waiting so long to paint the window for the first time, it should paint before loading the images, and paint before loading the javascript files (neither are critical to the overall layout)

An simplified outline of the HTML looks a bit like this

```
<html>
<head>
   <script> <!-- inline google analytic scripts -->
   <script> <!-- other inline script -->
   <link>
</head>
<body>
   <img>
   <img>
   <script> <!-- note : no async, not deferred -->
   <script> <!-- note : no async, not deferred -->
</body>
```

Any ideas?

[image: Waterfall for lonestarpercussion.com]

Comment: I didn't realize stack overflow would resize the image -- the green line on the right is the first paint event

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out - the waterfall was simply misleading. I created a small script that waited 10 seconds before returning to simulate a really large file, then replaced all of the references to images with the url to the script.

As it turns out, only the css in the head was blocking rendering - the rest of the files APPEAR to be blocking, but it's only a coincidence that they finish downloading right before the paint command.